# Random data search elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, random

Am using elasticsearch  , is it possible to generate random query search on elasticsearch ,instead of date ranges

like if I have 50000 doucments in 15 mins, I need only 1000 documents in same 15 mins,kind of random datas.

Any help would be really helpful :)

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Did not get you. `generate random query search`. Can you please elaborate a bit with the help of examples.

Comment: Thank you for the reply
For example , in kibana if  i create a data table visualisation and I want to relate hostname and port numbers

Hostname     Port    Count
test.com     443      30
test2.com    80       20
test3.com    53       10
tes4.com     22        5

This is arranged in count wise, i want some thing in random data order like this


Hostname     Port    Count
test2.com     80      20
test4.com     22       5
test.com      443     30
test3.com     53      10
Sorry for the word format
Thanks,
Raj